# How do I use getCountFromServer in a v2 onDocumentWritten cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a server side v2 cloud function (trigger) which has this header...

exports.userUpdatedTrigger = onDocumentWritten("users/{userId}", async (event) => {

As part of this function I want to use the new getCountFromServer function that does a count but does not need to read all the documents to do it.

```
 const countQuery = query(
        collection(db, "users"),
        where("account_id", "==", accountId),
    )
    const result = await getCountFromServer(countQuery)
```

The problem is that while I can deploy this, I get an error shown in the cloud console for this trigger when I update a user record (which triggers the onDocumentWritten).

The error is:

```
TypeError: collection is not a function
```

The imports I am using are:

```
const {
    FieldValue,
    getFirestore,
    getCountFromServer,
    query,
    collection,
    where,
} = require("firebase-admin/firestore")
```

I cannot find in the firebase doco which packages contain the 'query', 'collection', and 'where' functions.

Has anyone been able to get these two things working together, onDocumentWritten + getCountFromServer?

Or, has anyone been able to get getCountFromServer working at all in a cloud function? I can get it working client-side, but not server-side. I did manage to get onDocumentWritten working in simple form, before I tried to add getCountFromServer

See above.

I am expecting to be able to use getCountFromServer in a cloud function. I can get it working client side using the v9 API approach, but cannot get it working server-side.

Answer (score 3):

In server-side code the function is called `count()`, not `getCountFromServer()`:

```
const query = db
    .collection("users")
    .where("account_id", "==", accountId)
  

const snapshot = await query.count().get()
console.log("count", { count: snapshot.data().count })
```